# How to Extract emails Address from StringBuilder and set them into a list view in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a new android developer. I want to know how can I extract all email address from StringBuilder and then set them into a list view. I search everywhere but I don't find the exact solution. please help me with code/library or any other resources. I am totally Stuck.

Comment: If your StringBuilder instance contains email addresses then who put them in it? And how? All that it contains is text. Which text?

Comment: Please provide an example of your data, how is the Content in your StringBuilder structured? How do the data end up in the StringBuilder in the first place? Theoretically all you need to do is parse the data from your source into an Array and pass it to an ArrayAdapter that is used by your ListView as adapter.

Comment: inside StringBuilder large amount of String text data.

Comment: this is how i use the code 
`Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Element body = doc.body();
                builder.append(body.text());`

Comment: `inside StringBuilder large amount of String text data.` Yes. A string builder contains text. It can contain any text.

Comment: i have the String data now i want to extract email addresses from the string data and then show them into a listview. actually, I am trying to make an email extractor app. so how can I do that ?

Comment: `i have the String data` A string can contain any text. We do not know which text you have. Read the second comment.

Comment: @blackapps actually i use jsoup: Java HTML Parser (https://jsoup.org) for collecting all the text from any webpage. and then I store them into the String Builder. so all the text can contain email addresses. i just want to extract the email address from the text data. hope now u understand.

Comment: Read the first comment and the first sentence of the second comment. Since nearly an hour you refuse to give decent data.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using Jsoup. You should avoid StringBuilder int this case as it just adds extra processing but provides not benefit. To extract text you can easily narrow down the html code to your desired portion, split the String and retrieve your email addresses.
Use your web browser's utilities to examine the area of the website you should be concerned with. Then use Jsoup to narrow it down to that div/ tag or what have you.
For more information on how to do this, check the Jsoup documentation.